# Android Adapter for single item like ArrayAdapter is for a list?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

What Adapter should I use for a single item?  I use the ArrayAdapter for rows items.  Is there a simple adapter I should use when displaying just one item?

Comment: `AdapterView`s and their `Adapter`s are made specifically to display multiple items. If you only need the one, then you really don't need either of those things. You just need the `View` that you would have returned from `getView()`.

Comment: I need to have it update dynamically via notifyDataSetChanged.  (GPS information).  Can I do that without an adapter?

Comment: Sure. All `notifyDataSetChanged()` does, basically, is cause `getView()` to be called again for all the rows, because the backing list has been updated. Instead of all that intermediate stuff, you would just call `setText()` with the updated data on the `TextView` yourself, and similarly for whatever else you have in your item.

Comment: Great thanks.  Duplicate your comment as an answer I'll mark it as correct if you want.

Comment: Oh, I'm good. :-) Nothin' huge. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If u want to display single item then simply use text view and make it visible or invisible as per the logic of your code.